# Is it always necessary to repeat the pronoun before each verb?

Tags: pronouns, ellipsis

Is it always necessary to repeat the pronoun before each verb?

For example, do I need always to say:

> She called me and she said X

or can I use a shorter one

> She called me and said X

?

Comment: You can use the shorter one. It is even more common.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's perfectly okay to say -

> She called me and said X

Moreover, it is actually *encouraged* because repeating pronouns makes sentences **awkward**.
Only repeat pronouns if you think there will possibly be a confusion.

Comment: Sometimes repeating a pronoun *adds* confusion. *She called her mother and she said X* (who said X? She or her mother?) vs. *She called her mother and said X*--no confusion.

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. See my answer.

Comment: @Flimzy Exactly. Although I think that should be a comment on the question, not my answer...?

Answer (score 5):

Ellipsis<sup>1</sup> is not normally possible after other conjunctions besides `and`, `but` and `or`.

> *She didn't know where **she** was when **she** woke up.*

Contrary to:

> *He was not hungry, but had to eat*.

However, ellipsis of subject pronouns with forms of `be` is possible in some cases:

- *if possible*
- *when arriving*

Reference: [M. Swan - "Practical English Usage"](http://www.scribd.com/doc/11573706/Oxford-Michael-Swan-Practical-English-Usage)

<sup>1</sup> [Ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_%28linguistics%29) is omission from a clause of one or more words that would otherwise be required by the remaining elements.