# "I hope and (I) wish that the rest of the staff will be like you."

Tags: syntax, conjunction-reduction

Should I repeat on the pronoun "I" in the following sentence:

> "I hope and (**I**) wish that the rest of the staff will be like you."

Or is it enough to mention the pronoun in this case one time in the beginning?

Comment: Once is enough.  But did you really mean "stuff", and not "staff"?

Comment: In conclusion, I still don't understand what is the answer. and I don't understand why they called it "duplicate" while" I never saw the second question that I don't understand why is duplicate

Comment: Your question is supposedly a variation of this: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/310/is-it-always-necessary-to-repeat-the-pronoun-before-each-verb  Look at it, see if you think that it is not, and supply the argument by editing your question.  Or perhaps find the answer in it.

Comment: And that's why I got negative score here? 
I think that it's not nice when someone ask question to do that. There is way how to response. They could say for instance, "there is a question in the same way - link- but anyway the answer to your question is that you don't need to add pronoun one more time. If you would see the explanation etc. see there." it's simply, and respectably as well.

Comment: It is unpleasant to have your questions or answers downvoted, no doubt.

Comment: I think that practice exists to discourage users from asking questions that have already been asked and answered, and thus encourage searching for answers first.  Not sure it's effective, though.